# how to store adobe page maker data in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, adobe, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

One of the educational data was stored in adobe page maker file (.PMD) file. Which consist of scientific formulas like mathematical equations, chemistry formulas, I would like to store those data on a MSSQL database then represent in browser. I tried to read PMD file data using C#.NET unfortunately I didn’t get the results which I required.

1. Can anybody help me regarding this?
2. Is there any possible ways to read page maker data instead of C#.NET?
3. Is there any chance of getting the result if we convert the PMD file to another extension?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not familiar with PageMaker, so just speculating.

You can try to convert to Indesign file:

https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/open-pagemaker-files-indesign.html

Indesign has XML export and script support.